# "Highway sticker" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

What would you call a "highway sticker" in Spanish?

Highway sticker is a type of a sticker that drivers have to stick on their windshield as a proof of payment for using the highway.

[image]

Suggestion: muestra de la carretera, pegatinas de coche, pegatinas para coche.

Maybe there is no expression for that because in Spain they do not have them. But even if they would not have them, there has to be a name for it when the Spanish people travel in other countries..

I know that a sticker is *espina*, *abrojo*, *etiqueta*, and highway is *autovía*, *carretera*, *autopista*.

EDIT: could it be "**pegatina de peaje**"?

Comment: I think that the ones you have to pay for are _autopistas de peaje_ at least in Spain. Autovias are of a lesser standard than autopistas.

Answer (score 5):

It is difficult to tell, since this is a payment method that is not used neither in Spain nor in other Spanish speaking countries, as seen in Wikipedia's [List of electronic toll collection systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_electronic_toll_collection_systems).

Among other countries, I do know this paying system is used in Switzerland, where they call it [*Vignette*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignette_(road_tax)). Thus, I have heard either **vignette** or its Spanish equivalent **viñeta** (in fact, few days ago a friend of mine talked to me about it and used the Spanish version).
I see it mentioned in a [touristic site](https://www.tolltickets.com/country/swiss/vignette.aspx?lang=es-ES) giving hints about Switzerland.

In Spain old cars have to be checked once a year or so in a system called ITV (*Inspección Técnica de Vehículos*, vehicle technical inspection). Once you pass the check you get a sticker that you have to put in the front windshield:

> [image]

In this case, we always say **pegatina**.

This to say that there is not a fixed word for this and may depend on circumstances.

Further reading: [origin of the *viñetas*](http://www.1de3.es/2004/08/24/vinetas/) in the super blog 1de3.

Answer (score 4):

In Uruguay a type of [RFID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) chips is used with a system called [telepeaje](https://www.telepeaje.com.uy/). The telepeaje site refers to them as *pequeño sticker inteligente* or simply as *tag* or *sticker*.

Answer (score 2):

In Argentina, this payment method is not used. The use of the stickers is similar to what fedorqui suggests.

Here we say **oblea**.

[image: VTV Oblea]

(Verificación Técnica Vehicular - Technical vehicle verification)

**Updated 2019/04/30**

Now we have a rfid tag, “TELEPASE”.

[image: telepase]

Comment: I have added a new suggestion to the OP: pegatina de peaje

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the country. In Mexico windshield stickers are known as "**calcomanías**". There is even a rfid-like payment system in called **IAVE**, they put a sticker in your windshield and it gets detected automatically when you cross in the proper checkpoint; oddly enough the government is calling it "**tag**".